# Extremely slow query using CONNECT BY Oracle 10

Tags: sql, database, oracle, connect-by

I have a table `challenge` containing about 12000 rows. Every point connects to the four points around it, for example 100 connects to 99 101 11 and 189. I tried this with a small scale table and it worked just fine but as I increased the size of the table the query became exponentially slower and now it won't even finish. Here's my query

```
SELECT level, origin, destination
FROM challenge 
WHERE destination = 2500
START WITH origin = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE  PRIOR destination = origin;
```

Any advice on how to optimize this query would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add missing indexes on `destination`?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're finding every path from node 1 to node 2500 in a degree-4 graph (rectangular lattice?) of thousands of nodes. I expect there'll be quite a lot of them. Did the challenge just ask you to count them? Because I think the point was that you have to figure out how many there are by doing math, not brute force computation.

For example, if it's a 50x50 rectangular grid with node 1 and node 2500 in opposite corners, then the minimum path length is 100 steps. A path of 100 steps will have 50 of them horizontal and 50 of them vertical, and they can come in any order. Figure out how many ways you can arrange a string of 50 `H`'s and 50 `V`'s and you might find it's a number that even the mighty Oracle will have a bit of a problem with. (Generating the rows, that is. Doing the calculation just requires large integer arithmetic, which Oracle can probably do quite quickly once you tell it the formula.)

And your query is actually worse than that. It doesn't ask only for minimum-length paths. So it will also return all the paths of length 102 that take a step away from the destination somewhere along the way. And paths of length 104 that take 2 backward steps. And paths of length 2498 that visit almost all of the nodes! Counting those paths is more complicated than counting the short paths because you have to exclude the ones that cross themselves.

Comment: Yes Wumpus you are correct. It is a very large grid pattern or thousands of nodes where each one can connect to the ones directly around it. The problem with just using math is that there are a lot of specific nodes that only connect on certain sides, which is why I am trying to use the query. I would like it to return the origin, destination, and level for the shortest path. My definitions for the table are: create table challenge (origin int, destination int);
create index challenge_origin on challenge(origin);
create public synonym challenge for challenge;

Comment: It's a maze solver! In SQL! Surely a "use the wrong tool for the job to show your creativity" challenge then. Anyway the problem with your query is that it finds **all** paths. Adding `and rownum=1` would make it stop when it finds the first one, but it won't be guaranteed to be the shortest. For that you need a breadth-first search, and CONNECT BY is depth-first. Searching for "breadth-first" in oracle documentation yields this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm